# Turn off autocorrect of input using CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, autocorrect

I need to turn off autocorrect with CSS/JavaScript. I cannot specify it in HTML because I generate multiple inputs over and over and this autocorrect red underline is very disturbing in my case.

I want to apply all these statements with CSS or JavaScript, but it seems that it's not possible.

```
<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" />
```

Is there a way to generate multiple inputs without autocorrect underlining?

Comment: I don’t understand your claim that you can’t do it in html, or that “*it seems that’s not possible.*” What have you tried? For future reference, though: the [`::spelling-error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::spelling-error) pseudo-element. Also, as my final edit to this comment, please share your [mcve] code (in your question).

Comment: How are you generating them? Why don't you generate them with the attributes? You can't do this from CSS.

Comment: For what I ve googled, there was only HTML way of setting it. I use DOM to create input element and I assign to each different values in its for loop. I tried to insert them with innerHTML, but then it started to be a bit confusing. Thanks for the pseudo element! This is what I've been searching for

Comment: except that it's not supported by any browser :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the inputs already exist and you are unable to set their attributes at the time they are generated, then you could use `querySelectorAll` and then loop through the resulting nodelist to set their attributes like so:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off')
  input.setAttribute('autocorrect', 'off')
  input.setAttribute('autocapitalize', 'off')
  input.setAttribute('spellcheck', false)
})
```

```html
<input />
<input />
<input />
<input />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this using JavaScript:

```
inputs = container.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
  inputs[i].removeAttribute('autocomplete');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you maybe explain what do you mean by generating them without the custom attributes, please?